# Angular 2 ngFor over even/odd items

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a list with 2 columns, I want the left to show even indices and right to odd.

Currently I'm iterating the whole list for every column and filtering with ngIf="odd" or even.

Can I make ngFor only do and watch even or odd indices?

Would that improve the performance drastically? I don't know how much of a burden is it when half of the DOM elements are ng-if'ed out.

The list doesn't change frequently but when it changes it changes completely.

Comment: Please, show all the code you're using. Most likely you need to remap iterated array.

Answer (score 11):

You can create a pipe that only returns `odd` or `even` items

```
@Pipe({ name: 'evenodd' })
export class EvenOddPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value:any[], filter:string) {
    if(!value || (filter !== 'even' && filter !== 'odd')) {
      return value;
    }
    return value.filter((item, idx) => filter === 'even' ? idx % 2 === 1 : idx % 2 === 0 );
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | evenodd:'even'"></div>    
<div *ngFor="let item of items | evenodd:'odd'"></div>
```

Comment: couple of errors `':' expected. ` and `Cannot find name 'item'.`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated my answer. I think it should work now. If you still get errors, please provider more details (position of the error and exact error message).

Comment: Thanks for that really nice example of a pipe! I had to change the 7. line as following to get it run in Angular 4: `return value.filter((item, idx) => { return filter === 'even' ? idx % 2 === 1 : idx % 2 === 0; } );`

Comment: The `return` was redundant (thanks a lot for pointing it out). But otherwise it should work without `(...) ... { ... }` I'm not a TS pro though.

Comment: You still have to wrap parentheses around `item, idx` like `return value.filter((item, idx) => filter === 'even' ? idx % 2 === 1 : idx % 2 === 0 );`. Otherwise compile breaks with _Cannot find name 'item'._

Comment: I see. Sorry for my ignorance, but I'm not using TS actively. Learned something new :)