# (Angular) Using *ngFor to fill table

Tags: angular, html, bootstrap-4

I need a table structure somewhat like this:

[image]

For that, I'm using basic Bootstrap's table and the Angular's `*ngFor`. Each table cell is filled by a different name, coming from a back-end array. 
This is how I'm doing it:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of User;" class={{data.nome}} id='Check_{{data.id}}'
        (click)='toggleCheckbox($event.target)'>
        <td>{{data.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{data.nome}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The structure works fine, but the cells are not filled like I wanted. Each row is filled with the `same` name like this:

[image]

and I understand that this happens beacuse the ngFor is looping after the row changes, not for each new cell. The problem is that I can't fill the table correctly, and if I do, I can't keep the table's structure intact. 
 Is there a better way to achieve this? Using either Bootstrap or HTML5 is fine. 
 I believe the main problem here (and why I could not find a fitting answer online) is because I don't know the size of the array, so the size of this table is variable, for each, it will fill new cell while it still follows the structure.

Comment: Do you always want to have two columns? I think you need to create a new array and iterate through that

Comment: Your table has `<td>{{data.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{data.nome}}</td>` which is putting same data in both `td`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display two table columns per row in Angular 2 loop (Angular2 equivalent of PHP's array\_chunk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597438/how-to-display-two-table-columns-per-row-in-angular-2-loop-angular2-equivalent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create odd even filter like given here in answer

[Angular 2 ngFor over even/odd items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729757/angular-2-ngfor-over-even-odd-items][1])

and then use in your html like below

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of User | evenodd:'odd'">
      <tr class={{data.nome}} id='Check_{{data.id}}'
        (click)='toggleCheckbox($event.target)'>
        <td>{{data.nome}}</td>
      </tr>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngFor="let data of User | evenodd:'even'">
    <tr class={{data.nome}} id='Check_{{data.id}}'
        (click)='toggleCheckbox($event.target)'>
        <td>{{data.nome}}</td>
      </tr>
</ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think the answer is correct but the example will just make a `<tr *ngFor="let data of User"></tr>` might want to add `ng-container` for this.

Comment: Its not running with the `| evenodd:'odd'` or `| evenodd:'even'`, do I need any kind of import?

Comment: you need to create custom pipe as given here in first answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729757/angular-2-ngfor-over-even-odd-items
then it will work